# Trying to have save button disabled if object has empty fields

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I have a table with a blank row at the bottom for the user to fill out the fields and then hit a submit button. I want the submit button to be disabled if certain fields aren't filled out. I believe that I've created a function that should work but it isn't, why is that?

Here's the blank row that's displayed:

```
<tr>
  <td class="newRow"><input class='form-control' type="date" [(ngModel)]="newRow.date"  /></td>
  <td class="newRow">
    <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="newRow.fullhalf">
      <option value="full">full</option>
      <option value="AM">AM</option>
      <option value="PM">PM</option>
      <option value="(full)">(full)</option>
      <option value="(half)">(half)</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td class="newRow">
    <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="newRow.hours">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let h of hours">
          <option [ngValue]="h">{{h}}</option>
      </ng-container>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td class="newRow">
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newRow.scheduled" >
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
      <option value="scheduled">Scheduled</option>
      <option value="unscheduled">Unscheduled</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td class="newRow"><input class='form-control' type="text" [(ngModel)]="newRow.notes"  /></td>
  <td class="newRow">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="newRow.inPR" />
  </td>
```

here's my button:

```
<button [disabled]="!isSaveValid" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="float:right;" (click)="saveNewRow()" (onSave)="onSave($event)"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

and here's the function that I'm trying to use:

```
isSaveValid() {
    if (this.newRow.fullhalf == "" || this.newRow.hours == 0 || this.newRow.date == null)
        return false;
    else {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Try with `[attr.disabled]` instead of `[disabled]`.

Comment: @SrAxi `[disabled]` isn't the problem, I use it on my other buttons and it works fine

Comment: If you have taken the `<form>` then you can directly disable the button by checking whether form is valid or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

isSaveValid is a function, it should be isSaveValid() in html

Replace this:

```
<button [disabled]="!isSaveValid" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="float:right;" (click)="saveNewRow()" (onSave)="onSave($event)"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

By this:

```
<button [disabled]="!isSaveValid()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="float:right;" (click)="saveNewRow()" (onSave)="onSave($event)"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), they have a very simple way to do that :

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    myInput: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to disable it you may need `true : null` values.

Try this one:

```
[disabled]="!isSaveValid()  ? true : null"
```